# How to check Screen Capture Permission in MAC (10.15 - Catalina) with Electron?

Tags: macos, permissions, electron, screenshot, macos-catalina

Need to check Screen capture permission for my Desktop Application built With **Electron(1.7.10)**, tried **node-mac-permissions**, and **mac-screen-capture-permissions** libraries but didn't work or not supported with Electron 1.7.10. And ELectron Version Upgrade is not feasible for my Desktop Application as there are many methods deprecated in Latest Electron.

Answer (score 2):

I used `mac-screen-capture-permissions` on my electron 2 app and it's worked perfectly, So you should upgrade to electron 2. I think it's easy to upgrade from 1.7 to 2.0, because  only has [a few breaking changes](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-2-0#breaking-api-changes).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can check to enable from

```
System Preferences -> Security & privacy -> Screen Recording -> check your application
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a way to check the permissions from within the Electron app, not by hand.